# How should I call the Javascript api?

Tags: javascript, php

the gievn below is my API js Code....!!

how should i run or call??
using button click or onload ??

```
  var apikey = 'dadsafdshgfdhfgjhgbjhhkhfgewtwete';


  // Form your data object


 var listname = document.getElementById("listname");
  var email = document.getElementById("email");
  var fname = document.getElementById("firstname");
  var lname = document.getElementById("lastname");
  var mobile = document.getElementById("mobile");
  var country = document.getElementById("country");
  var designation = document.getElementById("designation");

  var subscriber_details = {
      listname      : listname,
      email         : email,
      prefix        : '',
      firstname     : fname,
      middlename    : '',
      lastname      : lname,
      telephone     : '',
      address       : '',
      city          : '',
      state         : '',
      pincode       : '',
      country       : country,
      mobile        : mobile,
      designation   : designation,
      company       : '',
      companyphone  : '',
      birthdate     : '',
      anniversary   : '',
      extra1        : '',
      extra2        : ''
   }
   // Send your data to your Juvlon account
   //

   call_juvlon_api(apikey, 'addSingleSubscriber', subscriber_details, function(response) {
       document.getElementById('show').innerHTML=response;
  });

</script>
```

I tried inserting the Javacsript code in Page but its not running..!!
so how I should Run or call the javascript api??

Comment: The script you have shown us is incomplete ( I suppose it is a typo ) and the information you provide about this api is insufficient.

Comment: @grimbode I had updated the full code

Comment: `how should i run or call?? using button click or onload ??` - depends _when_ you want to run it.

Comment: so which should i use??

Comment: @RiyaPatel : when do you want it ? on button click or on page load ?

Comment: i want it  on buttonclick

Comment: so how should i Call it?

Comment: @RiyaPatel :  please see my answer and mark it resolved if it helped you in some way!

Answer (score 0):

As you want the to use the API code on button click , you should use the following jQuery code :

```
$("#ButtonID").click(function(){
   //your API's code
});
```

OR you can call the event using the **`class-selector`** as :

```
$(".ButtonClass").click(function(){
       //your API's code
    });
```

**NOTE:** The class of the button should be unique. If there are similar classes on other buttons , you should better add a non-existing class to access it in your jquery code.

Eg :

```
 <button id="button1" class="btn btn-1a btn-success btnjquery"..../>
```

and use the class in jQuery as :

```
 $(".btnjquery").click(function(){
           //your API's code
        });
```

Comment: please study [this](https://api.jquery.com/click/) link for more clarification on `.click()` event!